# Audio Controller stop button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, audio, controls

I am trying to make an audio controller, but the stop button doesn't work. But I don't know why. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

`.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface myprojectViewController : UIViewController {

    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio;

}
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;

@end
```

`.m`

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LE" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender{
    [theAudio stop];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'theAudio' is a local variable in your start() method. You've declared it as a local variable, so it is out of scope in your stop() method, and you have an invalid reference. You need to use the class variable 'theAudio. Change :

```
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
```

to

```
self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
```